# Loop through html content using the ids in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am trying to loop through html content, for each html has a text input which i want to get the text value and pass it to the html span that also has id `replyJail-number` of the same with id of `replybefore-number`

**HTML PART**

```
<span id="replyJail-1" class="rep"></span>
<input id="replybefore-1" class="brp" type="hidden" value="hello"/>

<span id="replyJail-2" class="rep"></span>
<input id="replybefore-2" class="brp" type="hidden" value="#Bold letter"/>

<span id="replyJail-3" class="rep"></span>
<input id="replybefore-3" class="brp" type="hidden" value="`My code`"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
var x = document.getElementsById(id);
//x[i]
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var n = i++;
  var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
  var CODESOFTLAB = new Markdown.Converter(converter1);
  var before = document.getElementById("replybefore"+n).value;
  var MarckDowPreviewHtml = CODESOFTLAB.makeHtml(before);
  document.getElementById("replyJail"+n).innerHTML = MarckDowPreviewHtml;
  var a = 10;
}
```

Comment: `getElementById`--(Not `getElementsById` as itdoes not exist in JavaScript) returns only single element not collection...You have perfect markup to use `getElementsByClassName/querySelectorAll`

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsById(id);` is wrong, the right way `var x = document.getElementById(id);`

Comment: @Rayon: `getElementsById` isn't a function.  It's `getElementById` - no "s".

Comment: `var n = i++;` increments `i` an exrta time too (so your loop increments in 2s), you should probably use `n = i + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all input elements using `getElementsByClassName`. Now, iterate through each `input` and get the corresponding span's id by replacing "before" with "Jail". You can now insert the corresponding input's value in the target span as `textContent`.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("brp");
var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
var CODESOFTLAB = new Markdown.Converter(converter1);

for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ )
{
  var input = inputs[i];
  var value = input.value;
  var MarkDownPreviewHtml = CODESOFTLAB.makeHtml(value);
  var targetId = input.id.replace("before", "Jail");
  var targetSpan = document.getElementById( targetId );
  // targetSpan.textContent = MarkDownPreviewHtml;
  targetSpan.innerHTML = MarkDownPreviewHtml;
}//for()


<span id="replyJail-1" class="rep"></span>
<input id="replybefore-1" class="brp" type="hidden" value="hello"/>

<span id="replyJail-2" class="rep"></span>
<input id="replybefore-2" class="brp" type="hidden" value="#Bold letter"/>

<span id="replyJail-3" class="rep"></span>
<input id="replybefore-3" class="brp" type="hidden" value="`My code`"/>
```

Comment: how am i going to include this `var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
  var CODESOFTLAB = new Markdown.Converter(converter1);` it is my markdown converter it worked but doesn't convert any more

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code to include markdown converter code from your sample code.

Comment: Bahit what is the different between `innerHTML`  and `textContent` i this i printing the html content inside the text value as text instead of html can you change that?

Comment: @Alex updated the code. Please check if that is what works for you.